# ''Through'' or ''to''?

Tags: grammar

I would like to compare *through* and *to*. What is their difference in meaning? Which one is (more) correct (or are both correct)? The context can be found in the two sentences below.

- Julie went to school from September through June.
- Julie went to school from September to June.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct.  The first (with  "through") suggests that the school year ends *at the end of* June, whereas the second s(with "to") suggests that the school year ends *sometime during the month of* June.

However, in casual speech, the first might be understood the same as the second.  To be perfectly understood, specify the day of the month:

- Julie went to school from September 4 {to/through} June 12.

In that case, "to " and "through" might both be understood as meaning that June 12 was the *last day* of school.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are correct; "to" and "through" are both prepositions. Using "through" in that context makes it mean *up to and including*. Using "to" in that same context makes "to" express a point reached after a period of time. ("to" can also express a point reached at the end of a range, i.e *The worth of the product went from 10 dollars to 20 dollars.* (Keep in mind, for that kind of sentence you can't use "through".)