# What's the difference between from A to B and from A through B?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage

I've been reading a book. And I saw `from 1 through 5` the first time in my life. And I don't know the difference between `from ... through` and `from ... to`

My only guess is that `from 1 ... through 5` means from 1 incluisively to 5 inclusively.

And `from 1 ... to 5` means from 1 inclusively to 5 exclusively

So my Q is what does `from ... through` mean and what's the difference between `from ... thourgh` and `from ... to`?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60852/through-or-to#:~:text=Both%20of%20them%20are%20correct,after%20a%20period%20of%20time.

Comment: https://adislanguageschool.com/through-vs-to-until-in-english/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik still 50/50. Could you explain it to me using my examples?